# dm_exec_query_stats in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I recently started using PostgreSQL after using SQL Server for a while. Is there something like dm_exec_query_stats?

I haven't been able to find anything other than logging every long running query. I'm looking for something that won't fill up the disk quite as quickly.

Comment: the `pg_stat_statements` extension is probably the closest thing: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Comment: Not all Postgres experts are familiar with SQL Server details. You should explain the feature and add a link to MS documentation.

Comment: There's also `pg_stat_plans` - https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans - and the `auto_explain` module

Answer (score 0):

The information_schema is your friend for db stats. In addition, you can write a relatively simple query up against `pg_stat_activity` if your looking for detailed data on your queries. Cheers.